# Authentication for SuccessFactors and get all the entities

Tags: sap-successfactors

Authentication and get all entities using any api

Hi,
  I have to integrate the SAP SuccessFactors in our platform but how to authenticate the user I have seen two ways basic authentication and OAuth which one is secure ?And once authentication done I have to grab all entities available in it.Do we have any metadata api available?

Comment: be fair and accept the answer if helpful.

Comment: @dotchuZ thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call $metadata (e.g. https://apisalesdemo4.successfactors.com/$metadata) for a metadata overview (for each entity you see all options, filterable, upsertable etc.)

Always prefer OAuth over Basic Auth: OAuth is good than Basic Authentication, Basic Authentication's Drawback is , it is not that much secure. your credentials can be hacked. OAuth helps you in creating a secure passage for your access, and it uses RSA encryption as part of its setup, So OAuth is preferred one! from: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Difference-between-OAuth-and-Basic-Authentication-and-where/qaq-p/530513

Comment: Can you please provide the link about how to do the authentication for SAP successfactor? Searching the document but not getting proper information

Comment: https://blogs.sap.com/2017/03/05/how-to-initiate-an-oauth-connection-to-successfactors-employee-central/ or https://help.sap.com/viewer/3c4e8fc004cb4401a4fdd737f02ac2b9/7.5.6/en-US/d8716b276dcd48d58cc03c3b493bedf7.html